# DataValidationException when I create actuator endpoints

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, yaml, spring-boot-actuator

I have created Actuator endpoints in `endpoints.yml` file

```
info:
   '@name@':
   version: '@version@'
   buildNumber: '@buildNumber@'
   buildDate: '@buildDate@'
   buildBranch: '@buildBranch@'
```

When I try to execute I am getting a weird error:

> {"errorType":"NOT_FOUND","entity":null,"message":"No message available","fieldErrors":null}

In the console it says

> c.c.c.errors.BaseControllerAdvice - An unhandled exception was thrown, returning 500
>   org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource not found!

Expected output looks like

```
{"${spring":{"application":{"name}":{"version":"@version@","buildNumber":"@buildNumber@","buildDate":"@buildDate@","buildBranch":"@buildBranch@"}}}}
```

What might be causing this Error?

Answer (score 1):

I have added Dependency in order to enable the actuator points in order to know the info , health of the project the dependency which you need to add is

```
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId></dependency>
```